# Specify relative paths for server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In HTML I know I can specify relative paths such as:

`<a href="~/temp/Somecontent.xxx" />`

I want to setup relative paths for my server side code as well.  For example:

`File.Exists("../myBusinessLibrary/Bin/Debug/myBusinessLibrary.dll");//where this is a library that supports the web project`

The file can't be found.  I looked at `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and get:

`"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express"`

I don't think my assemblies are copied to this location.  Is there a way to setup relative paths that work with server side code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Server.MapPath(string relativePath):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.100).aspx

This method maps a relative path into a physical path that can be used in the File.Exists() method.

Comment: I should have known!  I dunno what it is, but I always forget about this mehod.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("relativepath goes here")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Server.MapPath`

```
var path = Server.MapPath("/myBusinessLibrary/Bin/Debug/myBusinessLibrary.dll");

File.Exists(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Server.Mappath and see what that gets you.  Here is the link to its information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx